# How to use the "-Property" parameter for PowerShell's "Measure-Object" cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, syntax, powershell-2.0

Why does

```
$a = GPS AcroRd32 | Measure
$a.Count
```

work, when

```
GPS AcroRd32 | Measure -Property Count
```

doesn't?

The first example returns a value of `2`, which is what I want, an integer.

The second example returns this:

```
Measure-Object : Property "Count" cannot be found in any object(s) input.
At line:1 char:23
+ GPS AcroRd32 | Measure <<<<  -Property Count
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GenericMeasurePropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

---

[This Scripting Guy entry](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/28/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-determine-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file.aspx) is where I learned how to use the "Count" Property in the first code sample.

The second code sample is really confusing. In [this Script Center reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176900.aspx), the following statement works:

```
Import-Csv c:\scripts\test.txt | Measure-Object score -ave -max -min
```

It still works even if it's re-written like so:

```
Import-Csv c:\scripts\test.txt | Measure-Object -ave -max -min -property score
```

I don't have too many problems with accepting this until I consider the [Measure-Object help page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315251.aspx). The parameter definition for `-Property <string[]>` states:

> The default is the Count (Length) property of the object.

If `Count` is the default, then shouldn't an explicit pass of `Count` work?

```
GPS AcroRd32 | Measure -Property Count # Fails
```

The following provides me the information I need, except it doesn't provide me with an integer to perform operations on, as you'll see:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> $a = GPS AcroRd32 | Measure
PS C:\Users\Me> $a

Count    : 2
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :

PS C:\Users\Me> $a -is [int]
False
```

---

So, why does Dot Notation (`$a.count`) work, but not an explicitly written statement (`GPS | Measure -Property Count`)?

If I'm supposed to use Dot Notation, then I will, but I'd like to take this opportunity to learn more about **how** and ***why** PowerShell works this way, rather than just building a perfunctory understanding of PowerShell's syntax. To put it another way, I want to avoid turning into a [Cargo Cult Programmer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60949/am-i-a-code-monkey/60986#60986)/ [Code Monkey](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60949/am-i-a-code-monkey/60951#60951).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you need to know is that in PowerShell generally, and particulary in CmdLets you manipulate objects or collection of objects.

Example: if only one 'AcroRd32' is running `Get-Process` will return a `[System.Diagnostics.Process]`, if more than one are running it will return a collection of `[System.Diagnostics.Process]`.

In the second case you can write:

```
(GPS AcroRd32).count
```

Because a collection has a count property. The duality object collection is also valid in CmdLets parameters that most of the time supports objects or list of objects (collection built with the operator `,`).

```
PS C:\> (gps AcroRd32) -is [object[]]
True
```

Just use the [Get-Member](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> (gps AcroRd32) | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Process

Name                       MemberType     Definition
----                       ----------     ----------
Handles                    AliasProperty  Handles = Handlecount
...                        ...
```

And

```
PS C:\>  Get-Member -InputObject (gps AcroRd32)

   TypeName: System.Object[]

Name           MemberType    Definition
----           ----------    ----------
Count          AliasProperty Count = Length
...            ...
```

Comment: `Get-Member -InputObject (gps AcroRd32)` - this helped me to understand where the `Count` Property came from.  Now I can see why my "complete statement" doesn't work, since it was the wrong syntax.  Thanks for showing me how to use `(GPS AcroRd32).Count`!

Answer (score 6):

Because the `COUNT` property is a property of the **OUTPUT** object (i.e. results of `Measure-Object`), not the **INPUT** object.

The `-property` parameter specifies which property(ies) of the input objects are to be evaluated. None of these is `COUNT` unless  you pass an array or arrays or something.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
gps AcroRd32 | measure-object | select -expand Count
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for the count you can do the following:

```
$a = GPS AcroRd32
$a.Count = 2
```

`$a = GPS AcroRd32` sets $a to an array of process objects. The array has a member call, Count, that will allow you to determine the number of elements already.

The [Measure-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx) commandlet (with alias `measure`) is used to measure the average, maximum, minimum, and sum values of a property.  So you could do something like `$a | measure -property Handles -sum` and get a count of the total number of open handles.